# Symbolic names for string interpolation

Tags: scala, string-interpolation

To my surprise this doesn't work -

```
implicit class LambdaContext(val sc: StringContext) extends AnyVal {
  def λ(args: Any*) = args
}

scala> λ"λx.x"
<console>:1: error: ';' expected but string literal found.
λ"λx.x"
```

Though it's a valid method name:

```
scala> new LambdaContext(new StringContext("λx.x")).λ()
res1: Seq[Any] = List()
```

Not sure if it's a bug or simple restriction.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but when you use `λ` in `λ"λx.x"` it seems to be considered an *operator* and for operators only *ASCII printable characters* are allowed. So, if you replace `λ` with something less fancy like `l` or `lambda`, it works.

```
implicit class LambdaContext(val sc: StringContext) extends AnyVal {
  def l(args: Any*) = λ(args)
  def λ(args: Any*) = args
}

scala> l"lx.x"
res1: Seq[Any] = List()
```